# vscode returning "Timed out waiting for launcher to connect" error, python runs perfectly in other text editors and in terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I got this error in VSCode, saying that it timed out waiting for the launcher to connect. I've tested it and Python works perfectly fine in command prompt and in other text editors. This is what it says: [VSCode error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M88TA.png) This is what my `launch.json` file is:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
    
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        },
        {
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't know what is wrong or how to fix it. It was working perfectly before and then it simply threw that error when it was running.

Comment: Hi @Peean and welcome to StackOverflow. It would be helpful if you'd simply copy the error message to your question instead of providing the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

[image]

Sorry, but it's a little weird of your debug command. Could you try to delete the Debug Console and try it again? And if it still does not work, could you attach the full outputs from the first line of the Debug Console?